# Django .is_superuser field permission

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

By default from project directory by running `manage.py createsuperuser` command I am able to create a superuser, but the `.is_superuser` flag is the default django flag to differ superuser or other user.

I don't want to use that because i am using that flag throughout the application to show settings menu. Instead, I added a field in my `userprofile models`, the field is `.is_primary_user`.

Is there any way to control that, so that if I run `createsuperuser` comment, it should update the `.is_primary_user` field by "1" in `userprofile` model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is, you have to catch the signal of the post_save of the User model, and if the `.is_superuser` is changed, you also change the `.is_primary_user`.

Has Brian Neal pointed out, you should not use the .is_superuser flag in your application. It is meant to be used along with Django permission system (a superuser has permissions for everything) and/or Django admin.

EDIT: I haven't tested, but it should be something like this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.contrib.auth import User

# method for updating
def update_primary_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     if instance.pk:
          return
     if instance.is_superuser and not instance.userprofile.is_primary_user:
          instance.userprofile.is_primary_user = True
          instance.userprofile.save()

# register the signal
pre_save.connect(update_primary_user, sender=User)
```

Comment: The above code is creating the profile.By default i set .is_primary_user value to "0" while creating new_primary_user how to set value to 1,should i write code to handle manually.

Comment: In that case you should use the pre_save, and add an "and instance.pk"  on the if of the update_primary_user

Comment: Hai,i tried with using using if instance.pk and changed post_save to pre_save,is_primary_user field is not updated.Any help will be great.

Comment: See the edition. if that doesn't work, you have to find your way out. instance.pk is always True unless it is the first save of the model.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: This is a website questions and answers. I provide you what I believe is an answer. If my answer does not work, either you update your question with relevant information about what is not working (e.g. is update_primary_user being called at all?) or you wait for other solution.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33713/discussion-between-user2086641-and-j-c-leitao)

Answer (score 1):

There are two options as I see it. One is on the post save signals for profile and user. The other is to override the profile save method.  The later will only handle new users.

The [post save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) for either the user model or the profile model can be used for updating the profile models is_primary_user. Then not only when you run the createsuperuser program can you update the profile accordingly, but if you give an existing user superuser rights, it will also update that users profile. The problem with using the user model signal is that the profile may not yet be created. You probably would need to catch signals for both models. One for if a user is updated (user model), and the other (profile model) for if the user is being created.

Another option is to override the profile save method. You could check the user.is_superuser that it is linked to and then update the is_primary_user field accordingly.

On the other hand, you maybe wanting to do this for only the first superuser which is created in which case you would first need to check if any superusers previously existed.

I agree with two other posters that it would be best not to use the is_superuser flag in this manner.